# Can we get the contents of Cordova Inappbrowser Webpage loaded dynamically

Tags: php, angularjs, cordova, inappbrowser, payumoney

Is there anyway to get the page contents of the webpage browsed in inappbrowser? 
I was building a payment gateway and after the payment, failure or success will be simply redirected to my own webpage where i will print the data in the php like

```
 print_r($_POST);
```

so all the json response will be printed on the webpage. I want this response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: nope. i have put the parameters in the url and done my work...

Comment: use POST they said..it's more secure they said...now back to using GET :-)

Comment: i didn't get you but i will say how i have done it. After the payment, i have redirected page to a dummy url like "http://paymentresponse/payment_status/payment_msg" and i have written the code like when inappbrowser url contains the string paymentresponse then simply i read the status and msg and displayed the user whether the transaction is ok or not. I didn't get any help so i followed this approach.